# How do i know if my execute method carried out a successful delete?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I was looking into ResultProxy class which seems to be the result of the `execute` method.

I started with a simple select and just iterated over the results.  The thing i was curious about though was Update and Delete.  How do i know if the delete is successful?

When doing it in python, I would have something akin to:

```
result = session.execute("delete from A where id = 4")
```

and it runs it, but I have no clue it was successful other than attempting to query the existence of id=4.

When I was looking at the class ResultProxy, I didnt see anything related to `isSuccessful` or any other keyword that jumped out to me.

Like i said, normally, I just iterate over the set for selects but cant quite figure this out.

Comment: By successful, do you mean that it deleted something? Or just that it was executed?

Comment: item was successfully deleted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can look at the [`rowcount`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.rowcount) property:

```
if result.rowcount > 0:
    print("deleted something")
else:
    print("nothing deleted")
```

Note that the accuracy of this attribute depends on the database and your query. For SQLite in particular and simple `DELETE FROM foo WHERE bar = :baz` queries it should work.

Comment: So, in this case, would `result` be a list of the items deleted?

Comment: @Fallenreaper No. `result` is the result of `session.execute()`, a `ResultProxy` instance. For `DELETE` queries, `result` is an empty iterable.

Comment: Ah, ok. rowcount is the number of affected rows.  Cool thank you.